# Kubectl commands not working after adding proxy

Tags: docker, kubernetes, proxy, ip, virtual-machine

I have installed a Kubenetes deployment (version:1.19.14) with docker version 20.10.8 on unbuntu 18.04.

I was able to install it and was working fine.
Due to some reason internet connectivity was lost on the host and on some finding I found that proxy settings were erased.
When I added the proxy the internet connectivity started working but strangely I was not able to give kubernetes kubectl commands anymore.

While trying kubectl commands after exporting proxy, the following error pops up:

**Unable to connect to the server: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exeeded while awaiting headers)**

We exported the proxy in the following manner:

**export http_proxy=http://proxy.example.com:80**

**export https_proxy=$http_proxy**

I searched and was suggested somewhere to make the proxy persistent through http-proxy.conf and reload the daemon:

**sudo systemctl daemon-reload**

**sudo systemctl restart docker**

Even after doing this the kubectl commands didn't work.

Please let me know how can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Kubectl is just a CLI that communicates with the api-server of the Kubernetes control plane. First of all you need to make sure that the api-server is running and healthy, and that this is not the source of your problem.

You can use the tool crictl to debug pods when Kubectl is not working. It takes directly to the underlying container runtime which would be containerd if you are using Docker.